# Rome visa-free transit area: Can I move between Terminals 1-3 freely?

Tags: schengen, transit, transit-visas, rome, fco

I've booked flights for next Tuesday and my ticket issuer has given me some cause for concern (after the fact, of course). I'm transiting in FCO (Rome, Italy) to EVN (Yerevan, Armenia).

I carry cabin luggage only. There is a 5.5 hour layover time. I am not of a nationality that has "rights" to enter the Schengen Area, nor do I have a Schengen visa, but I am also not on any red lists requiring an type A (airside transit) Schengen visa. For example, in 2021 I overnighted in Frankfurt without hassles, leaving for another non-Schengen country in the morning.

Is there a path avoiding passport control, which I can use to move between terminals 1-3 freely?

Comment: Can you confirm your citizenship? Some citizenships require ATVs for airside transit in all Schengen countries, while for others it varies from one transit country to another. Also are both your flights on the same ticket, or are they booked separately?

Comment: Is this on the same itenary? If its self connection, you will be denied boarding from the origin.

Comment: @jcaron "I am also not on any red lists requiring an type A (airside transit) Schengen visa."

Comment: If your two flights are booked together on the same ticket, there should be no problems.

Comment: Flights are booked on same ticket. Called Rome airport yesterday and they suggested my nationality will not have any requirement for an airside transit visa.

Comment: @Engineer Just to be sure, you aren't going with WizzAir?

Comment: @Anders Yes, I am changing from LATAM to WizzAir in Rome (for the trip to Yerevan). Why?

Comment: WizzAir doesn't do connections, not even between their own flights. I doubt you have those flights on one ticket. If the flights are not on the same ticket there is a high risk of LATAM denying you boarding since you aren't allowed to enter Italy.

Comment: @Anders Thanks. I have those flights on one itinerary, from kiwi.com. However, they suggested after all was paid for, that "The self-transfer travel hack makes travel cheaper by combining separate flights, train, or bus tickets into unique itineraries. 
Example: A direct ticket from New York to Prague is more expensive than 2 separate tickets New York → Amsterdam and Amsterdam → Prague, so we book you these separate flights... This isn’t an official itinerary offered by the carriers and they won’t take responsibility for the unofficial connections."

Comment: @Anders You can provide that as an answer which I will accept, if you wish.

Comment: @Engineer one itinerary from Kiwi doesn't mean one ticket. One ticket means when you check the booking on the airline's website, all the flights show there under the same PNR. You have a LATAM ticket to Rome and a Wizzair ticket to Armenia. If you don't have a Schengen visa, LATAM will not allow you to board your flight, because as far as LATM is concerned, your destination is Italy. Whether you plan to leave Italy after a few hours, or don't plan to enter Italy is not relevant to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Rome visa-free transit area: Can I move between Terminals 1-3 freely?

Most likely no. This is a self transfer and you are responsible for having the required documentation which in this case will most likely means "you need to be able to legally enter Italy" It's highly unlikely that Latam will let you board otherwise. Whether you have a second ticket is immaterial to them.

Kiwi is clear about this: https://www.kiwi.com/en/help/kiwi-com-travel-hacks-258/article/self-transfer-travel-hack-131/

> You might need to leave the visa-free zone (the area behind security control, where the gates are) during layover to recheck your baggage, check in for your next flight, change terminals, or simply because of the airport’s design.

Comment: It could be clearer. Even if you do not need to leave the visa-free zone (flights in the same terminal, online check-in, no checked bags), you still need to be _allowed_ to enter the transit country in order to be allowed to board the flight.

Comment: @AndrewRay: in most but not in all cases. There are countries that allow visa free self connection and if you are lucky that is reflected in Timatic. It depends on whether you can sweet talk the check in agent to accept it.

Comment: That we've had this question four times this week and that in every case the proposed itinerary will not work demonstrate that Kiwi _is not clear enough_.

Comment: @AndrewRay That is an interesting bit of meta-information. Would you mind linking those other questions, please?

Comment: @Engineer [Transit visa Dammam? Istanbul? (a _double_ self-transfer)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178197), [Transit visa in Dammam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177704), [Transit Visa at DMM Dammam, Saudi Arabia? (deleted)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178171), and this one. As a bonus, [Do I need a transit visa for a 3.5 hours in Dammam (DMM) airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175588) is from a few months ago.