# Transit Visa. - Dammam? Istanbul?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, saudi-arabia, saw

I am travelling from Cologne (Germany) to Delhi (India) through Istanbul (Turkey) and Dammam (Saudi Arabia). I am an Indian Citizen. Do I need a transit visa? For both? I have no check-in bags.

[image]

Comment: Note that you seem to be taking a significant risk with this itinerary. Connection times seem reasonable, but a small Friday in one of the flight can easily make you miss one. Since these are (I think) separate tickets you'll need to buy new tickets in this case.

Comment: Kiwi is on the roll selling all those Pegasus-Air India self-transfers via Saudi Arabia apparently. As if one self-transfer wasn’t bad enough, two of them here!

Comment: Indeed, kiwi is all in, even from Frankfurt

Comment: @Dino There are plenty of better options like a direct FRA-DEL on Vistara, FRA is a 1h train ride from Cologne and will have no attached risks to it

Comment: Arguably, this is _not_ a duplicate because it's a double self-transfer.